# anyone knows any open skeletal/bones 2d animations framework for java?

Tags: java, 2d, animation, skeletal-animation

Some examples could be the animations framework used in [Aquaria](http://www.bit-blot.com/aquaria/), or in [Crimson Legend](http://marctenbosch.com/skeletal2d/).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by that? Simply hierarchical transforms? Some sort of skinning? Ragdoll? IK?

Comment: I am looking for something simple, no rag dolls, no inverse kinematics, only animations made with a skeleton and key frames, in 2d. I think that what I really want to know is which format is used for those kind of animations and if exists an application and/or a java library to edit and load them, respectively. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most developers simply create their own tools; there is no standard format that I know of.

Part of the reason for that is it's a relatively straight-forward task once you have written the code to display such a keyframe. It's a trivial step from that to add some basic functionality to move and rotate each bone, and save the set of transforms as a keyframe. From there, you need only add some controls for the timeline, and you have yourself an editor!

That said, I was able to find this editor, though you'll have to write the loading routines yourself:
http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/590509

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not what you're looking for but JME has support for skeletal animation: http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/wiki/doku.php/animation.

Comment: I know jmonkeyengine, I have used it in the past, but it is not what I am looking for right now. Thanks for the answer.